# Best solution for enterprise endpoint patch management

Tags: windows

The environment: A landscape of 4500+ endpoints connected to a corporate network, of which most but not all devices are Windows Desktop devices. The devices are managed by a local / on-prem AD NOT Azure. The devices are not managed by Office O365

The problem: We need an easy way to manage and deploy patches to the endpoints on the network.

The investigation done so far: WSUS is an solution, but without a management tool the supporting it will be a nightmare. SCCM is also an option but I don't see SCCM being sold as a standalone package any more and we want a solution just for endpoints. Intune needs Azure AD which we don't have.

Potential solutions: Solarwind Patch Manager

My Ask: Please provide me guidance as to cost effective, operationally viable solutions to the problem.

Comment: I think WorkspaceOne meets all your requirements.